# Lebesgue measure not complete

Tags: measure-theory

How can one show that the Lebesgue measure is not complete on $(\mathcal{R}, \mathbf{B}(\mathcal{R}))$?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ has the cardinality of the continuum. [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) too and moreover it has measure $0$. Hence there's at least a subset of Cantor set which is not measurable.

Answer (score 0):

*How:* You would have to give an example of a subset of measure zero with a subset which is not measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a subset $C$ of measure zero, and $|C|=|R|$, notice that the set of Borel sets has the same cardinality as $R$.